# Creating invisible folder with batch

Tags: batch-file, mkdir, invisible

How to use

```
mkdir or md
```

but make the folder invisible...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need the attrib command to set the "hidden" attribute, assuming that when you say "invisible" you actually mean what Windows calls "hidden":

```
mkdir foo
attrib +h foo /s /d
```

Comment: Could you yet explain what is +h, /s, and /d ?

Comment: And yes... by "invisible" I mean hidden... so only people with which turned on option in "Folder Options" can see it.

Comment: run "help attrib" in a command prompt for more information. +H makes it hidden, /s recurses through the folder (and is needed for /d), /d applies to folders rather than files.

Comment: Not sure what you are proposing with `/s /d`. `attrib +h foo` works perfectly fine (Win XP SP3, Win 7 SP1).

Comment: @AndriyM Fair enough - I didn't know that!